# Show all numbers that are not in table

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following problem.
I have more than 60,000 numbers in my DB2 database and I need to check which of them are not found in my table.

I would like to have the output as follows:

```
number | found | not-found
010012 |x      |
010023 |       |x
```

Depending on that I have to create either an UPDATE or an INSERT.
I already created the UPDATE statement with all the numbers. That`s not the problem, however, finding out which of the numbers are missing or not I cannot figure it out.

This is my SELECT which of course does not work as expected.

```
SELECT
    a.Field1 || a.Field2,
    CASE WHEN a.Field1 || a.Field2 IN ('010012', '010023')
    THEN 'Found'
    ELSE 'None'
    END 
FROM TEST_TABLE.U56 a
WHERE Field1 || Field2 IN ('010012', '010023');
```

Comment: removing `, '010023'` in the case clause would at least make a similar result

Comment: So, you have a table with 60k numbers in it, and you need to find which ones are missing... according to another list? What list?

Comment: Do you want to insert if not found? And what do you want to update if found? Maybe you can just do a merge of all numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH 
NUMBERS (NUMBER) AS
(
  VALUES 
    '010012'
  , '010023'
)
,
MY_TABLE (NUMBER) AS
(
  VALUES 
    '010012'
  , '010012'
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  N.NUMBER
, CASE WHEN T.NUMBER IS NOT NULL THEN 'x' END AS FOUND 
, CASE WHEN T.NUMBER IS     NULL THEN 'x' END AS NOT_FOUND
FROM NUMBERS N
LEFT JOIN MY_TABLE T ON T.NUMBER = N.NUMBER
```

| NUMBER | FOUND | NOT_FOUND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 010023 |  | x |
| 010012 | x |  |

If it's not what you need, then please, edit your question with a complete example with sample data for both tables and the result desired.